# Before removal, check to see if there are any relations

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

Before I remove the Account, I want to know if there are any Hiringorg and/or Transfer linked to that Account.

When there is still a Hiringorg and/or Transfer, then I want to get a alert saying: Remove Hiringorg and / or Transfer first.

How exactly do I go about this?

**AJAX**

```
//Function of the delete button inside the Modal.
    $('button#delete').click(function() { //delete comes from id='Delete' on line 166 in index.php
        var id=$('input#deleteID').val(); //deleteID comes from id='deleteID' on line 162 in index.php
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {
                id:id,
                action:"deleteAccount"
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status){
                    location.reload();
                }else{
                    alert("Please remove the HiringOrg and/or Transfer.")
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Jquery**

```
function deleteAccount($id){
    global $conn;

    $checkHir = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT * 
        FROM cfg_hiringorg 
        WHERE account_id =".$id);
    $checkHir->execute();

    $checkTrans = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT * 
        FROM cfg_transfer
        WHERE account =".$id);
    $checkTrans->execute();

    if (!$checkTrans AND !$checkHir) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM cfg_accounts WHERE id=".$id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $success = $stmt->rowCount() ? true : false;
        return ['status' => $success];
    }
}
```